# np.reshape 1d array to 2d array - choosing right dimensions

Tags: python, numpy

I'm trying to reshape a 1d array to a 2d array with numpy's reshape:

```
import numpy as np
inputArray =np.random.randint(low=0, high=4, size=160000)
inputArray_ = inputArray.reshape(-1,4000, 4000,4)
```

Which returns a value error:

```
ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 160000 into shape (400,400,4)
```

Comment: What's the confusion?

Comment: Have you tried it without last parameter(the '4')? `inputArray_ = inputArray.reshape(-1,400, 400)`

Comment: There is a typo (4k vs 400), and it's very unclear what's actually tripping you up.

Comment: Reshape can't change the total number of elements.  The product of the shapes has to match.

Answer (score 2):

Use

```py
inputArray_  = np.reshape(inputArray, (-1, 2))
```

Or

```py
inputArray_ = np.reshape(inputArray, (len(inputArray)/2,2))
```

Comment: Use `//2` instead of `/2`.

Answer (score 0):

since 400*400*4 = 640,000 is bigger than 160000  you cannot reshape.

You don't have enough values to fill the new shape.

640,000-160,000 = 480,000.   you lack 480,000 values.

divide your shape of 160000 by the other dimensions-multiplicated, if a int is the result, it works.

e.g.

```
inputArray_ = inputArray.reshape(-1,40, 40, 10)
```

this will result in a shape of [10,40,40,10]

since  160000 / (40*40*10) = 10  ---> 10 is the dim that the "-1" takes